# Inserindo documentos MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho o seguinte documento(Schema):

```
var CandidatoSchema = new Schema ({
    id_login: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    nome: String,
    cpf: String,
    dataNascimento: Date,
    sexo: String,
    estadoCivil: String,
    endereco: {
        endereco: String,
        numero: Number,
        bairro: String,
        complemento: String,
        cep: String,
        uf: String,
        cidade: String
    }
});
```

Tenho um Form com estes campos, quando o usuário clicar no botão `Salvar` ele vai enviar os dados para minha rota `cadastro`:

na minha rota cadastro tenho um `console.log(req.body)`: que mostra os dados enviados.

```
{ nome: 'NomeSs',
  cpf: 'xxx.xxx.xxx-xx',
  endereco:
   { endereco: 'rua alameda',
     numero: '111',
     bairro: 'bairro',
     complemento: 'compras',
     cep: '111-111' }
```

Estou tendo dificuldade para inserir os dados em documentos `embedded`, neste caso não está inserindo os dados referentes ao `endereco`.

Minha função para inserir:

```
exports.Add = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var person = new Person();

    // Tentei usar está linha, mas não funciona...
    person.endereco.push(req.body.endereco);

    person.save(function(err, person) {
        if(err) res.sendStatus(500);
            res.sendStatus(201);
    });
};
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer para inserir documentos `embedded`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, sua propriedade *endereco* não é do tipo array para você estar fazer um push. Ele é um tipo objeto.

Se você executar `person.endereco = req.body.endereco` você conseguiria atribuir o valor.

Mas ainda melhor, se você fizer `var person = new Person(req.body)` já irá criar o objeto com todos os valores atribuídos.

Comment: o `push` viajei mesmo... muito obrigado... funciono certinho aqui...